# Change a particuar view in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am new to android developing and I am currently stumped at this situation.

Is there a way to change a particular child view of a fragment?

For example, I have a TextView and Button in a Fragment. Now after inflating this fragment and committing it, I would like to only change the text of the TextView based on the user input.

EDIT: The same layout is used to create multiple fragments. I would like to just change the TextView of a particular Fragment.

MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button bt;
EditText et;
LinearLayout ly;
String m;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.badd);
    ly=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_ver);
    et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etadd);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // multiple fragments are created
            MyFragment f=new MyFragment();
            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction t=fm.beginTransaction();
            t.add(R.id.sv1, f, "hi");
            t.commit();
            et.setText("");
        }
    });
//would like to change the text of the textview of the fragment
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
} 
}
```

Fragment Code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_lay, null);


    return v;
}
}
```

activity_main XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/lay_ver"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_hor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etadd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:hint="Enter Subject"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/badd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layfrag"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.53"
        android:text="HiHow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button2"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Please show us what you already tried and where are you exactly stucked. We are not a code maker community ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a list of Fragments in your activity and each fragment to the list when you create them. Then you can get the fragment you want to change and do as cdblades said :

```
View parent = fragment.getView();
View childTextView = (TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.myChildTextView);
```

But why are you adding the fragments in the same container?

Comment: Because I want it to be displayed in the same activity. I want to identify each TextViews created in the fragments to edit them later.

If there is a way without using a fragment, please do tell.

I just want to use a particular block of layout repeatedly in a single activity and at the same time be able to edit the views in the block.

Answer (score 0):

The base View class has the findById() method that you can use to get a reference to child views like so:

```
View parent = fragment.getView();
View childTextView = (TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.myChildTextView);
```

Comment: Yeah, but how will this help if I were to use the same layout for creating different fragments. The id associated with the TextView will be the same.
Sorry. I should have added this in my original question. Will edit it immediately.

Comment: @saurabh if you call findViewById() on a fragment it will look in the fragment's own view hierarchy so you shouldn't have a problem

Comment: @saurabh schopy is right, but I'll expand by pointing out that findById() is available for every View object, and will search the hierarchy under the View it is called on.